# Delaying a timed interval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function set up like so:

```
setInterval(function () { get_fb(); }, 10000);
```

I'd like to reset the timer to 10 seconds whenever a user does something (like hover over an element or click an element)

How would I tell the program to do something like this?

Comment: With reset you mean something like "if 5 seconds elapsed, reset to 10"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is you assign the timer to a variable you can clear it and restart it like this:

```
var timer = setInterval(get_fb, 10000);

$('#foo').click(function() {
    clearInterval(timer); // stop timer

    // do something...

    timer = setInterval(get_fb, 10000); // restart timer
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var timeout = setInterval(function () { get_fb(); }, 10000);


 //to reset interval, first clear it
 clearInterval(timeout);
 //then re-create
 timeout = setInterval(function () { get_fb(); }, 10000);
```

Comment: `clearTimeout` is used with `setTimeout`, `clearInterval` is used with `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

In the event callback, clear the interval, and then set the interval anew:

```
interval = setInterval(...);
...elsewhere...
$(..selector..).click(function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(...);
});
```

Be sure that `interval` is accessible within the scope of the click callback.